# Java ConcurrentModificationException without iterating through it

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

Im trying to program a java Domino game without an interface atm and I am having the concurrentModification exception and im not adding or deleting while iterating it. Moreover, when I am iterating through them I am just printing their values

I have designed a class system with a class Player that has a List. In this class I delete the dominoes of each player.  I have tried iterating with an iterator but I dont see any changes.

```
do {
            if (counter >= players.size()) {
                counter = 0;
            }
            Player p = players.get(counter);
            System.out.println("It is " + p.getName() + " turn");
            if (lastdominoes.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("There is no dominoes in the table. Please make a move:");
            } else {
                for (Entry<String, Domino> e : lastdominoes.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.print("The last dominoes played are:");
                    System.out.print(e.getValue().toString());
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Your dominoes are:");
            int numberaux = 0;
            String dominoesnumber = "";
            Iterator<Domino> iteratordominoes = p.getDominoes().iterator();
            while (iteratordominoes.hasNext()) {
                Domino d = iteratordominoes.next();
                System.out.print(d.toString());
                dominoesnumber += " " + numberaux + "  ";
                numberaux++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf(dominoesnumber);
            System.out.println("Please choose a domino:");
            int choosenDominoNumber = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("You are about to move the Domino" + p.getDominoes().get(choosenDominoNumber).toString());
            placeaDomino(p, p.getDominoes().get(choosenDominoNumber));
            System.out.printf("\n\n");
            if(p.endofGame()){endofgame=true;}
            counter++;
        } while (!endofgame);
```

This is the place a domino method

```
 public boolean placeaDomino(Player p, Domino d) {
        if (playedDominoes.isEmpty()) {
            playedDominoes.add(d);
            unplayeddominoes.remove(d);
            lastdominoes.put(d.getDirection(), d);
            p.makeaMove(d);
            return true;
        } else if (lastdominoes.get(d.getDirection()).match(d)) {
            playedDominoes.add(d);
            unplayeddominoes.remove(d);
            lastdominoes.put(d.getDirection(), d);
            p.makeaMove(d);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and the p.makeaMove basically just removes the domino

```
public void makeaMove(Domino d){
        this.dominoes.remove(d);
    }
```

### this is an execution of the program so it gets more clear

```
 How many players you want to play with
2
There are 2 players in this table
It is Player 1 turn
There is no dominoes in the table. Please make a move:

Your dominoes are:
3/5 2/2 2/6 3/3 5/3 4/5 1/6 
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6  Please choose a domino:
2
You are about to move the Domino2/6 

Then exception occurs
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1239)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.listIterator(ArrayList.java:1099)
    at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:299)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.iterator(ArrayList.java:1095)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(AbstractCollection.java:282)
    at dominolibrary.Player.makeaMove(Player.java:72)
    at dominolibrary.Table.placeaDomino(Table.java:116)
    at dominolibrary.Table.<init>(Table.java:79)
    at dominolibrary.DominoLibrary.main(DominoLibrary.java:18)
Java Result: 1
```

What I want to do in each iteration is to delete a domino from the players domninoes until one players list is empty.

Comment: Is the first snippet in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, all the first snippet is in the constructor